# Intellij IDEA writes logs (using log4j) following the ConversionPattern but without going to new line

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea, log4j

running my selenium suite with Intellij IDEA I'm facing this issue:
I configured correctly log4j using this properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d  %p  [%c{1} : %L]  -  %m%n
```

logs are following the pattern but are written ALL IN ONE LINE in this way:

```
2016-05-03 11:34:05,612  INFO  [CreateTicketPage : 68]  -  clicked on save button2016-05-03 11:34:05,627  INFO  [TicketDetailsViewPage : 27]  -  Ticket Details View.page.successfully.loaded2016-05-03 11:34:07,452  WARN  [AddTransactionPage : 44]  -  Add Transaction.page.successfully.loaded2016-05-03 11:33:52,032  INFO  [TestRunner : 25]  -  executing TestRunner.setup
```

**%n** seems ignored!! but running the tests using just ***mvn clean install*** in the command line everything look perfect. any suggestion?? is this an Intellij related issue??